# TensorFlow: Is it possible to map a function to a dataset using a for-loop?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor, map-function

I have a `tf.data.TFRecordDataset` and a (computationally expensive) function, which I want to map to it. I use TensorFlow 1.12 and eager execution, and the function uses NumPy ndarray interpretations of the tensors in my dataset using `EagerTensor.numpy()`. However, code inside functions that are given to `tf.Dataset.map()` are not executed eagerly, which is why the `.numpy()` conversion doesn't work there and `.map()` is not an option anymore. Is it possible to for-loop through a dataset and modify the examples in it? Simply assigning to them doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not exactly.

A Dataset is inherently lazily evaluated and cannot be assigned to in that way - conceptually try to think of it as a pipeline rather than a variable: each value is read, passed through any `map()` operations, `batch()` ops, etc and surfaced to the model as needed. To "assign" a value would be to write it to disk in the .tfrecord file and just isn't likely to ever be supported (these files are specifically designed to be fast-read not random-accessed).

You could, instead, use TensorFlow to do your pre-processing and use `TfRecordWriter` to write to a NEW tfrecord with the expensive pre-processing completed then use this new dataset as the input to your model. If you have the disk space avilable this might well be your best option.